# Trigger a build in pipeline script at SCM Change of a special file

Tags: jenkins, svn, build, triggers, version-control

Project Folder is an external in a svn checkout. In this folder is a file, what should be used as trigger for a overnight build. Just on SVN change of this file a build should be triggerd. I used the option with includedRegions, but I reached no success. What could be false?

```
stage('Checkout AppBuilder Repository'){
        steps{
           checkout([$class: 'SubversionSCM', 
           additionalCredentials: [], 
           excludedCommitMessages: '', 
           excludedRegions: '', 
           excludedRevprop: '', 
           excludedUsers: '', 
           filterChangelog: false, 
           ignoreDirPropChanges: true, 
           includedRegions: '.*/Aenderungslisten.vi/.*', 
           locations: [[cancelProcessOnExternalsFail: false, 
             credentialsId: "${env.SVN_CRED_ID}", 
             depthOption: 'infinity', 
             ignoreExternalsOption: false, local: './AppBuilder', 
             remote: "${env.APP_BUILDER_URL}"]], 
             quietOperation: false, 
             workspaceUpdater: [$class: 'CheckoutUpdater']])
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the notice. I'm new in stackOverflow

Comment: If I am not mistaken this configuration belongs to Jenkins. If yes I would recommend to add one of the `Jenkins` tags as in my opinion this would make it easier for others to understand your environment you are working in.